# Creating Workflow with SharePoint Designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-designer

I am kinda new to SharePoint and I have to create a very simple WF, but that actually I am not able to do it through SharePoint Designer.

I have got a document library, where users upload some project request, and a list of customers. When a new project request is created, this is associated to a customer of the existing list. Each customer has got some data, like a column for Project Manager and another column for Technical Supervisor. I have to create a WF where the Project Manager and the Technical Supervisor get an email if a project of their own customer is created or modified.

I tried using a List WF at first, but then I thought it could not act outside of my document library, but even using a Site WF it seems I am not able to let it gets data from the list.

Anyone could explain to me this Step-by-Step?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

So you have two lists:

List 1 - Project Request Document Library

List 2 - Customer List
This list has columns like Project Manager, Technical Supervisor and Customer Name?

The way that I would do it is to add a Lookup column to List 1, that looks up the Customer Name Column from List 2. In the additional fields part, bring over any other fields that you want too (Project Manager, and Technical Supervisor).

This will allow you to show the following in List 1:
Project Request Document | Customer Name | Project Manager | Technical Supervisor

Then create a workflow on List 1 - go to List > Workflow Settings > Create a Workflow in Sharepoint Designer.

Give the workflow a name, then type 'email' choose 'Send an email'.

```
Click on the 'these users' link - then click the little Address Book near the 'To' field.
Select Workflow Lookup for a User > 
Data Source: Current Item > 
Field from Source: Technical Supervisor or Project Manager >
Return field as: Email Address
```

Publish the workflow, then there is one final step to do.

Click on the workflow name in the left panel and in the 'Start Options' panel on the right select:
Start workflow automatically when an item is created
Start workflow automatically when an item is changed

Save, then publish and you're done!

Comment: Thank you so much @sean! So do you confirm that it is not possible to get data from another list directly with the workflow?

Comment: You can get data from another list, however you need something to be common between the two lists to allow you to match it.

You can for example change the Data Source to List 2, but then it will ask you to find a list item in your list. I use a similar thing for our holiday request form. On 1 list I have all the employee names, and their holiday allocation / remaining days, and the other is an Infopath form. It matches the 'Name' field that is common between both lists and updates the number accordingly. Hope this helped and didn't confuse you further!

Comment: Then you can pull the information across - follow the same information listed above. Click the address book > Workflow Lookup for a User > Data Source: Your Customer / Technical Supervisor List Name > Field from Source: Technical Supervisor > Find List Item - Field: Customer name in the contact list that you have > Value: Customer Name in the Project Request. I think this should work, although it's early and I haven't had a cup of tea yet.